# How do I scrape the favorite_count of a tweet on someone's timeline?

Tags: python, twitter, scrape

If I run my code without the final line: `getVal(tweet['retweeted_status']['favorite_count']),` then the scrape works but when I add this line I get an error message `KeyError: 'retweeted_status'`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
q = "David_Cameron"
results = twitter_user_timeline(twitter_api, q)
print len(results)
# Show one sample search result by slicing the list...
# print json.dumps(results[0], indent=1)
csvfile = open(q + '_timeline.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
csvwriter.writerow(['created_at',
                'user-screen_name',
                'text',
                'coordinates lng',
                'coordinates lat',
                'place',
                'user-location',
                'user-geo_enabled',
                'user-lang',
                'user-time_zone',
                'user-statuses_count',
                'user-followers_count',
                'user-created_at'])
for tweet in results:
    csvwriter.writerow([tweet['created_at'],
                    getVal(tweet['user']['screen_name']),
                    getVal(tweet['text']),
                    getLng(tweet['coordinates']),
                    getLat(tweet['coordinates']),
                    getPlace(tweet['place']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['location']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['geo_enabled']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['lang']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['time_zone']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['statuses_count']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['followers_count']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['created_at']), 
                    getVal(tweet['retweeted_status']['favorite_count']),
                    ])
print "done"
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of `print tweet` right after `for tweet in results`?

Comment: If the key can be missing just use dict.get `getVal(tweet.get('retweeted_status', {}).get('favorite_count', 0)`

Answer (score 2):

According to the API over at https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets this attribute may or may not exist.

If it does not exist you will not be able to access the attribute. You can either make a safe lookup using the in operator to access it by checking existence first

`retweeted_favourite_count = tweet['retweeted_status']['favourite_count'] if 'retweeted_status' in tweet else None`

or doing the way of assuming it is there but handle when it is not

`try:
    retweeted_favourite_count = tweet['retweeted_status']['favourite_count']
except KeyError:
    retweeted_favourite_count = 0`

Then assign the retweeted_favourite_count value in write row function.

Also your CSV header row is lacking a description for retweeted favourite count

Updated example:

`for tweet in results:
    #Notice this is one long line not two rows.
    retweeted_favourite_count = tweet['retweeted_status']['favourite_count'] if 'retweeted_status' in tweet else None
    csvwriter.writerow([tweet['created_at'],
                    getVal(tweet['user']['screen_name']),
                    getVal(tweet['text']),
                    getLng(tweet['coordinates']),
                    getLat(tweet['coordinates']),
                    getPlace(tweet['place']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['location']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['geo_enabled']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['lang']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['time_zone']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['statuses_count']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['followers_count']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['created_at']),
                    # And insert it here instead
                    getVal(retweeted_favourite_count),
                    ])`

You coulse also switch the line:

`getVal(tweet['retweeted_status']['favorite_count'])`

With as Padriac Cunningham suggested

`getVal(tweet.get('retweeted_status', {}).get('favourite_count', None)`

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks so much for the quick response. I think I understand your logic here but I am very new to python so not really sure where to add this into the code. I've tried a number of combinations with no success. Thanks also for noticing the missing CSV header. I've now corrected this.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect where you should put it. Try playing around with creating a basic dictionary in python and trying to access values that exist or not exists if you want to get an understanding of why the problem arises.

Comment: Thanks again Jon for the help. This didn't actually work for me, but I did manage to get the code to run in the end. I have posted my corrections in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, for anyone who sees this in the future... I managed to get the code to work using the below. getVal(tweet['favorite_count']) gives the favorite count for a tweet.

```
q = "SkyNews"
results = twitter_user_timeline(twitter_api, q)
csvfile = open(q + '_timeline.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
csvwriter.writerow(['created_at',
                'user-screen_name',
                'text',
                'language',
                'coordinates lng',
                'coordinates lat',
                'place',
                'user-location',
                'user-geo_enabled',
                'user-lang',
                'user-time_zone',
                'user-statuses_count',
                'user-followers_count',
                'user-friend_count',
                'user-created_at', 
                'favorite_count',
                'retweet_count',
                'user-mentions',
                'urls',
                'hashtags',
                'symbols'])
 for tweet in results:
    csvwriter.writerow([tweet['created_at'],
                    getVal(tweet['user']['screen_name']),
                    getVal(tweet['text']),
                    getVal(tweet['lang']),
                    getLng(tweet['coordinates']),
                    getLat(tweet['coordinates']),
                    getPlace(tweet['place']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['location']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['geo_enabled']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['lang']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['time_zone']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['statuses_count']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['followers_count']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['friends_count']),
                    getVal(tweet['user']['created_at']), 
                    getVal(tweet['favorite_count']),
                    getVal(tweet['retweet_count']),
                    tweet['entities']['user_mentions'],
                    tweet['entities']['urls'],
                    tweet['entities']['hashtags'],
                    tweet['entities']['symbols'],
                    ])

print "done"
```

where getVal, getLng and getLat are defined earlier in the code by:

```
def getVal(val):
    clean = ""
    if isinstance(val, bool):
        return val
    if isinstance(val, int):
         return val
    if val:
         clean = val.encode('utf-8') 
    return clean

def getLng(val):
     if isinstance(val, dict):
         return val['coordinates'][0]

def getLat(val):
     if isinstance(val, dict):
        return val['coordinates'][1]

def getPlace(val):
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        return val['full_name'].encode('utf-8')
```